# Mongodb $lookup on array of objects/documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

The document schema for my `orders` collection is given below:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("Id of this record"),
    "location_data" : {
        "type" : "main",
        "location_id" : ObjectId("this location's id")
    },
    "item_details" : [
        {
            "item_id" : ObjectId("this item's id"),
            "qty" : 950
        },
        {
            "item_id" : ObjectId("this item's id"),
            "qty" : 200
        }
    ]
}
```

I have `items` stored in a different collection whose schema looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("this record's id"),
    "title": "this item's title",
    "description": "this item's description"
}
```

My desired output would be:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("Id of this record"),
    "location_data" : {
        "type" : "main",
        "location_id" : ObjectId("this location's id")
    },
    "item_details" : [
        {
            "title": "this item's title",
            "item_id" : ObjectId("this item's id"),
            "qty" : 950
        },
        {
            "title": "this item's title",
            "item_id" : ObjectId("this item's id"),
            "qty" : 200
        }
    ]
}
```

In Mongodb doc I haven't found anything to work with array of objects. Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the following Aggregate query:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    {$unwind : "$item_details"},  // Since the item_details is an array, unwind it first
    {$lookup:     // run the $lookup to join with `items` collections
        {
            from: "items", 
            localField: "item_details.item_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "item_detailsTemp"
        }
    },
    { 
        $addFields: { "item_details" : { $mergeObjects: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$item_detailsTemp", 0 ] }, "$item_details" ] } } // Replace the existing item_details with new information 
    },
    {
        $group : { // Since you've ran the $unwind at early stage, group it to make the item_details as an array again
           "_id" : "$_id", 
           "location_data" : {$first : "$location_data"}, 
           "item_details" : {$push : "$item_details"}}
    }
])
// Voila! Hope this helps!
```