# how to apply mongodb lookup on _id inside an array in mongodb document

Tags: mongodb

I am facing a problem in running mogodb aggregate lookup function on array  object id of document
i have two document from different tables
Department Table document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60b5d01d3cad3268ec30a4db"),
    "designationId" : [ 
        ObjectId("60b5d6483cad3268ec30a513")
    ],
    "creationTime" : 1622525747967.0,
    "isActive" : true,
    "name" : "CT Dept One",
    "organizationId" : ObjectId("60b5cf7d3cad3268ec30a4c7"),
    "brandUserId" : ObjectId("60ae11608646230e9cea8ee9"),
    "createdby" : ObjectId("60ae11608646230e9cea8ee9"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-06-01T06:13:49.639Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-06-01T06:40:08.453Z"),
    "__v" : 1
}
```

Designations Table

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60b5cf7d3cad3268ec30a4c7"),
    "creationTime" : 1622525747965.0,
    "isActive" : true,
    "name" : "CT PVT LTD",
    "brandUserId" : ObjectId("60ae11608646230e9cea8ee9"),
    "createdby" : ObjectId("60ae11608646230e9cea8ee9"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-06-01T06:11:09.783Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-06-01T06:11:09.783Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I have tried every solution return mention here
[Mongodb $lookup on array of objects/documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58884620/mongodb-lookup-on-array-of-objects-documents)
to get data from Designations table in to department table.
please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: please provide your lookup

Comment: @mohammadNaimi i am not able to do and result which i found on above link is for older version of mongodb. can you please help me to right lookup for what i want

Answer (score 0):

```
Documents.aggregate([{
$lookup:{
    form:"DesignationsCollection" // Designations collection name
    localField:"designationId"
    foreignField:"_id"
    as : "designation"
}
}])
```

Comment: thanks for you answer but i have tried it already lookup is not working in this way

Comment: lookat this https://mongoplayground.net/p/5lo7I_QN5IK